# Attach a QToolButton to a specific column in the header on a QTreeWidget

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I can't seem to find an answer to this I would like to Attach a QToolButton to a specific column on a QTreeWidget. Ideally I would like it on the right side of the column with some text on the left. I have worked out how to attach it to the first column with no text but I would like it on the 3rd column.

I think the answer is in using setItemWidget and headerItem but can seem to get them working at all.

If anyone could advise that would be amazing.

```
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class Main_window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(900, 500)

        self.tree = HTreeWidget()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class HTreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)

        self.header_labels = ["header 1", "header 2", "header 3", "header 4"]
        self.setColumnCount(len(self.header_labels))
        self.setHeaderLabels(self.header_labels)

        header = self.header()

        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(header)
        button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.DownArrow)
        button.clicked.connect(self.menu)

        action_group = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        self.filter_checked_out = action_group.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Filter 1', self, checkable=True))
        self.filter_checked_in = action_group.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Filter 2', self, checkable=True))
        self.no_filter = action_group.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('No Filter', self, checkable=True))
        self.no_filter.setChecked(True)

    def menu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)

        menu.addAction(self.filter_checked_out)
        menu.addAction(self.filter_checked_in)
        menu.addAction(self.no_filter)

        menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor().pos())

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main_window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So would like header 3 to have a drop down list with a list of filters. with the ability to extend that eventually to header 4 with a different drop down list.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this but feels like there should be a better way to achieve the results I want. I will leave this code here just encase someone ells needs it.

```
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class Main_window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(900, 500)

        self.tree = HTreeWidget()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class HTreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)

        self.header_labels = ["header 1", "header 2", "header 3", "header 4"]
        self.setColumnCount(len(self.header_labels))
        self.setHeaderLabels(self.header_labels)

        self.header = self.header()

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.header)
        self.btn.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.DownArrow)
        self.btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(15, 15))
        self.btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(15, 15))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.menu)

        self.header.sectionResized.connect(self.on_column_move)
        self.header.sectionMoved.connect(self.on_column_move)

        action_group = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        self.filter_checked_out = action_group.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Filter 1', self, checkable=True))
        self.filter_checked_in = action_group.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Filter 2', self, checkable=True))
        self.no_filter = action_group.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('No Filter', self, checkable=True))
        self.no_filter.setChecked(True)

    def on_column_move(self):
        self.btn.move(self.header.sectionPosition(2) + self.header.sectionSize(2) - 20, 3)

    def menu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)

        menu.addAction(self.filter_checked_out)
        menu.addAction(self.filter_checked_in)
        menu.addAction(self.no_filter)

        menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor().pos())

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main_window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes that is a means to an end but the more pythonic way of doing this would be to create your own Header class that inherits from the standard header class or its parent which you then augment with the features you are wanting for your new header style.  Doing so would allow you more control over how the whole thing works as well give you a class that you can then plug and play with later on.  Basically what you are really wanting to do is replace a String header cell with a Widget header cell